# Декор experts__decor не хочет скрываться под experts__statistic

Tags: html, css, frontend, scss

Декор experts__decor не хочет скрываться под experts__statistic
Умоляю, кому не сложно, помогите

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&family=Roboto&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&family=Philosopher:ital@1&family=Roboto&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@800&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@700&display=swap");
@font-face {
  font-family: "Rubik-Bold";
  src: url(/Font-Family/Rubik-Bold.ttf);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Rubik-Regular";
  src: url(/Font-Family/Rubik-Regular.ttf);
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus,
:active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

input :-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

button :-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a,
a:fisited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:focus,
:active {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active {
  outline: none;
}

nav,
footer,
header,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1057px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
.header .container {
  display: flex;
  height: 114px;
  align-items: center;
}
.header__menu {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.header__button {
  flex: 0 0 252px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
.header__button .button-blue {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  padding: 15px 29.64px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
}
.menu__item {
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.menu__link {
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: raleway;
}

.health {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 153px;
  padding-bottom: 48px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 135px;
}
.health::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 70%;
  background-color: #ec5863;
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}
.health__row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 66.59px;
}
.health__title {
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 55.44px;
  font-family: Rubik-Bold;
}
.health__title span {
  color: #4285f4;
}
.health__text {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #616161;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 16.62px;
  letter-spacing: 0.96px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.health .button {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #ec5863;
  padding: 14px 31.33px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: raleway;
  color: white;
}
.health__watch {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.health__text-watch {
  padding-left: 12px;
  line-height: 16.38px;
  letter-spacing: 1.04px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #b0b0b0;
}
.health__text-watch p {
  font-size: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 1.485px;
  color: #000;
}

.button {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #ec5863;
  padding: 14px 31.33px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: raleway;
  color: white;
}

.corona {
  margin-bottom: 197.93px;
}
.corona .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.corona__img {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 187px;
}
.corona__img::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -27px;
  left: -47px;
  height: 147px;
  width: 147px;
  background-color: #ec5863;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.corona__img::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 440px;
  left: -10px;
  height: 77px;
  width: 77px;
  background-color: #ec5863;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.corona__decore {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 330px;
  left: 215px;
  height: 77px;
  width: 77px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #ec5863;
}
.corona .corona__decore-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 471px;
  left: 42px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.49);
  height: 27px;
  width: 206px;
}
.corona__body {
  max-width: 379px;
}
.corona__title {
  font-size: 44px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: Rubik-Bold;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  line-height: 126%;
}
.corona__title span {
  color: red;
}
.corona__text {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 138.5%;
  letter-spacing: 0.96px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-family: Rubik-Regular;
}

.experts {
  background: #fafbfd;
  margin-bottom: 195.59px;
}
.experts__statistics {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 117px;
  width: 654px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 24px 0px rgba(88, 126, 236, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 79.07px;
}
.experts__decor {
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #ec5863;
}
.experts__decor_one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 84.5px;
  left: -28px;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.experts__decor_two {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 97px;
  width: 97px;
  transform: rotate(105deg);
}
.experts__decor_three {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 590px;
  width: 127.467px;
  height: 127.467px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.experts__number {
  color: #ec5863;
  font-size: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 5.04px;
  font-family: Rubik-Bold;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
.experts__value {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4.07px;
  font-family: Rubik-Bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.experts .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.experts__block {
  margin-right: 104.83px;
}
.experts__title {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Rubik-bold;
  font-size: 44px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 126%;
  margin-bottom: 12.07px;
}
.experts__title span {
  color: #587eec;
}
.experts__text {
  color: #616161;
  font-family: Rubik-Regular;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 138.5%;
  letter-spacing: 0.96px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="description" content="On this site I will study CSS, HTML and Java Script">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Java-Script, JS, Java Script, HTML, CSS, SCSS, SASS, Home">
  <title>MyprojectS4</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="./img/i.webp">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header__logo">
          <div class="header__img"><img src="img/COroNA/Logo.png" alt="#"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="header__menu menu">
          <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">FEATURES</a></li>
          <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">SUPPORT</a></li>
          <li class="menu__item"><a href="#" class="menu__link">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="header__button">
          <a class="button-blue" href="#">DOWNLOAD</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <main class="main">

      <section class="health">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="health__row">
            <div class="health__body">
              <div class="health__title">Take care of yours <br> family’s <span>health.</span></div>
              <div class="health__text">All in one destination for COVID-19 health queries. <br> Consult 10,000+
                health workers about your concerns.</div>
              <div class="health__button">
                <a href="" class="button">GET STARTED</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="health__img"><img src="./img/COroNA/Doctor.svg" alt=""></div>
          </div>
          <div class="health__watch">
            <div class="health__button-watch"><img src="./img/COroNA/whatch.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="health__text-watch">
              Stay safe with GoCorona
              <p>Watch Video</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="corona">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="corona__img">
            <img src="./img/COroNA/Phone.png" alt="phone">
            <div class="corona__decore"></div>
            <div class="corona__decore-bottom"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="corona__body">
            <div class="corona__title">Stay safe with Go<span>Corona.</span></div>
            <div class="corona__text">24x7 Support and user friendly mobile platform to bring healthcare to your
              fingertips. Signup and be a part of the new health culture.</div>
            <div class="corona__button"><a href="" class="button">Features</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="experts">
        <div class="experts__statistics">
          <div class="experts__body">
            <div class="experts__number">2m</div>
            <div class="experts__value">Users</div>
          </div>
          <div class="experts__body">
            <div class="experts__number">78</div>
            <div class="experts__value">Countries</div>
          </div>
          <div class="experts__body">
            <div class="experts__number">10.000+</div>
            <div class="experts__value">Medical experts</div>
          </div>
          <div class="experts__decor experts__decor_one"></div>
          <div class="experts__decor experts__decor_two"></div>
          <div class="experts__decor experts__decor_three"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="experts__block">
            <div class="experts__title">Talk to<span>experts.</span></div>
            <div class="experts__text">Book appointments or submit queries into thousands of forums concerning health
              issues and prevention against noval Corona Virus.</div>
            <div class="experts__button"><a href="" class="button">Features</a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="experts__img"><img src="./img/COroNA/Group 26.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```